# Using @ConfigurationProperties with nested properties in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have been trying to figure out how to use `@ConfigurationProperties` with nested properties in Kotlin, as one can do in Java.

**Example**
Given the following properties defined in application.properties:

```
first.id.=application1
first.second.id=application2
```

I have tried:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "first")
class First {
    lateinit var id: String
    lateinit var second: Second

    class Second {
        lateinit var id: String
    }
}
```

However it does not initialize the nested property:

**Error:** `lateinit property second has not been initialized`

I have not been able to find any documentation on how to do this in Kotlin. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try @PropertySource

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think with Kotlin you need to initialise the `second` variable.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "first")
class First {
    lateinit var id: String
    var second = Second()

    class Second {
        lateinit var id: String
    }
}
```